# SourceMaps.loadSourceMapContents: Could not download sourcemap from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js.map

Tags: angularjs, debugging, google-chrome-extension, visual-studio-code

I am trying to debug my web app with vscode and framework angular.js I have downloaded debuging for chrome extentions but when start the program display the follow error on debug console.

```
SourceMaps.loadSourceMapContents: Could not download sourcemap from https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js.map
```

My file launch.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    ]
}
```

My html code where call angular.min-js:

```
 <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/todo.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/todo.css">
  </head>
```

The web app is in IIS localhost. Do you have any suggestions to solve this? or another method to debug angular app and build web app.

Comment: As a workaround, you could try with the non-minified version of angular: Replace `angular.min.js` with `angular.js`.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem with follow steps:

1. download source from https://angularjs.org/
2. reference the source as a file src="../js/angular.min.js"
3. Modify "webRoot" in launch.json. add /JS/ here is where stored javascripts file.

launch.json

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [

        {
            "name": "Launch Chrome against localhost",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "launch",
            "url": "http://localhost/index.html",
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/JS/" 
            ,"diagnosticLogging": true,
            "sourceMaps": true
        },
        {
            "name": "Attach to Chrome",
            "type": "chrome",
            "request": "attach",
            "port": 9222,
            "webRoot": "${workspaceRoot}/JS/",
             "sourceMaps": true

        }
    ]
}
```